# Creating a macro in haml that changes the children or parent element

Tags: macros, haml

I have the following haml pattern that I use very often:

```
%p.wording{:'data-wording-key' => 'some.key'}
  = Wording.fetch('some.key')
```

I wonder if I can create a helper or macro to write it as

```
%p{wording: 'some.key'}
```

And have it generate the same HTML as would the first version.

Is this possible with haml ?

---

Another acceptable approach would be to have

```
%p
  = WordingMacro('some.key')
```

And have `WordingMacro` add the class and data-attribute on the parent `p` tag. But is that feasible ?

---

Yet another fine approach would be to declare my own elements, such as

```
%p_with_wording('some.key')
```

and have it generate the same html. But can you create your own elements in haml, pass params to them, and then change their children elements ?

Comment: I think you have a typo in your first code block – an extra colon at the start of `:'data-wording-key':`?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there are no macros in haml but you can easily create a helper method in whatever language you are using with haml.

Another option that may be more fitting for this case is to use a partial. Put you common code in the partial:

```
%p.wording{:'data-wording-key': key}
  = Wording.fetch(key)
```

And then call it in your main haml file:

```
= partial( :wording_partial, { key: 'one-key' } )
```

if you are using sinatra. In rails it would be something like:

```
= render_partial :wording_partial, locals: { key: 'one-key' }
```

The partial rendering is done with the language you use haml with - it is not part of haml itself.